# mirror-api java quick start project deploy to app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-glass, google-mirror-api

can anyone help me as to how to deploy the mirror-api java quick start project to google app engine? I have imported the project into Eclipse via the maven import and made the war file: mvn war:war
I am able to run it locally without any problems
dont know how to deploy to app engine, I have created an appspot project inside google app engine as well

Answer (score 0):

check it out https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-java/tree/app-engine

there's a tag on official repo!